# Copy nginx.conf file into the container when container is launched

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have nginx.conf file on our artifactory (http://artifactory.abc.com). I want to dowload and replace the file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) inside the container when the container is launched so that I do not have to rebuild the Dockerfile each time I make a change to my nginx.conf file. I can just upload the modified file to artifactory so how can I configure Dockerfile to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a normal docker copy command after downloading file in your local

```
docker cp nginx.conf <container name/id>:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: I want to write a command inside Dockerfile to copy the file when the container is launched.

Comment: @codechef You can use ENTRYPOINT Instruction for this at the end of your Dockerfile

Comment: My Dockerfile looks like - 

        FROM artifactory.com:5102/dataservices/nginx:1.12

        EXPOSE 80
        EXPOSE 443

        RUN apt-get update \
       && apt-get install -y netcat telnet nmap net-tools dnsutils wget curl 
       iputils-ping vim \
       && apt-get install -y tcpdump

       ENTRYPOINT ["docker cp https://artifactory.com/artifactory/http-
       store/nginx/nginx.conf nginx:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"]
       CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

I get the error saying no such file or directory so it's unable to reach https I think.

Comment: @codechef Just create a shell script where you do a wget for "artifactory.com/artifactory/http- store/nginx/nginx.conf" and copy the script inside container. Now in your entrypoint just run this script.

Answer (score 0):

Use a read-only bind mount when running your container:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf,target=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf,readonly ...
```

Comment: I want to write a command inside Dockerfile to do the same and not issue the command during docker run.